# Create 3D Grid from opposite vector coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, grid

I'm looking for a way to create a 3D grid based on two opposite endpoints (`a=(x1,y1,z1) and b=(x2,y2,z2)`) of the cube. The step size is 1 in each dimension.
Just found some numpy fcts that start with `(0,0,0)`, in my case though the starting point is variable and negative (e.g. `(-5,-10,-15)`).

Comment: Is it always the case that `x1 < x2` etc?

Comment: yes, e.g. starting point a = (-5,-10,-15). opposite point b = (10,20,30). Grid should be like g = [(-5,-10,-15), (-5,-10,-14),...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehensions FTW!

```
xRng = range(a[0],b[0]+1)
yRng = range(a[1],b[1]+1)
zRng = range(a[2],b[2]+1)
g = [(a,b,c) for a in xRng for b in yRng for c in zRng]
```

Comment: Of course, if you didn't want to go all the way to `(10,20,30)` you could leave off the `+1` which would go to `(9,19,29)`

Comment: Thx! I started implementing the grid myself and basically did it like you except for the list comprehension. Thought there would be a numpy fct. that does it while only providing the endpoints as parameters... thx again for your help

Comment: There may well be a numpy function, but I don't know it. Feel free to upvote or accept my answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.ogrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) (or [`np.mgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) if you want a dense grid):

```
>>> x1, y1, z1 = -4, -3, -2
>>> x2, y2, z2 = 4, 3, 2
>>> np.ogrid[x1:x2, y1:y2, z1:z2]
 [array([[[-4]],

       [[-3]],

       [[-2]],

       [[-1]],

       [[ 0]],

       [[ 1]],

       [[ 2]],

       [[ 3]]]),
 array([[[-3],
        [-2],
        [-1],
        [ 0],
        [ 1],
        [ 2]]]),
 array([[[-2, -1,  0,  1]]])]
```